# How to select a range if first and last row values are in cells

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this has a very obvious solution but I'm stuck.
My goal is that by clicking on a button a certain range of cells is copied to the clipboard. The range of cells that needs to be copied is the same for each identifier (column E) and I have specified it in columns F and G as the start and end rows, and in column H the range address complete with the columns.

My worksheet disposition is:

[image]

I do not really see what the syntax would look like for:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("xxx").Range (xxxxxxx).Select

Selection.Copy
```

being `Thisworkbook.Sheets ("xxx")` the active sheet.

I have tried a few combinations using INDIRECT and INDEX but I think I don't get it. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: range(range("h1").text).copy  would copy the range whose address was stored in H1 as text - is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the address from the desired range in column H

```
Dim MyAddress As String
MyAddress = Thisworkbook.Sheets("yyy").Range("H14").Value 'read the cell where your address is
```

And use this address to copy the desired range

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("xxx").Range(MyAddress).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for copying is:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("xxx").Range (xxxxxxx).Copy Thisworkbook.Sheets("destinationSheet").Range(destinationRange)
```

Avoid using `Select` :)

Comment: Actually that's the syntax for copy & paste ;) While the OP just wants to copy to the clipboard: *"a certain range of cells is copied to the clipboard."* (which means without pasting it)